# Facebook videos don't play with IE9 & Flash Player

Tags: video, flash, internet-explorer-9, facebook

After installing the latest version of Adobe Flash Player for Internet Explorer 9, videos on Facebook don't play. Whenever I try reverting to an older version of Flash Player, I am just forced to update to the latest version.

I've read online that Flash Player 11.3 is not compatible with Windows 7 64-bit and IE9. This is my exact setup! How can I get Facebook videos working again?

Comment: Can you describe what happens in more detail? Does the video get stuck as "Loading..."? Does it respond when you click the play button? ... I am also using IE9, Flash Player 11.3, and Windows 7 64-bit. But I am not experiencing this issue. Try [disabling hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html).

Comment: i can see the play icon and the pevious image but when i click its blakc screen on the embed video on the news feed ... that is pretty weird, im tryinh to install and older version of flash BUT I CAN'T this is getting crazy, the dont let me install and older version anywhere on the web  ... ;(

Comment: not previous image preload image* sorry my english is not perfect

Comment: if you have a link where i can install an older version of flash without having to go threw adobe it would be great, like that they wont ask me to install newest version ... and then i could see if thats the problem or not

Comment: Did you try disabling hardware acceleration? See the link in my first comment. This may be related to your graphics drivers.

Comment: yes ive try this, i did enable it and then disbale it, for the embed video from youtube or vimeo on facebook the logic stand when enable it work when diable it didnt work BUT for video post by a friend directly on facebook (not via a website) it still do the same thing when i click play black screen and stay like that ... ;( im so tired of this snif snif tkx for ure help

Comment: *I've read online that Flash Player 11.3 is not compatible with Windows 7 64-bit and IE9.* Flash 11.3's problems are in no way exclusive to Windows 7 or IE9. Flash 11.3 continuously crashes my Chrome 20 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Dennis There's apparently a [new security feature](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Flash#Flash_Player_11.3_Protected_Mode_-_Windows) introduced in 11.3 ("protected mode") that's been causing issues. While that link is for Firefox, the instructions to disable "protected mode" don't look browser specific, so may be worth trying.

Comment: @Bob: Sadly, that only seems to apply to Windows Vista and above.

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade Flash, first follow the following steps for uninstalling version 11.3:

1. Download the official [uninstaller](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/support/uninstall_flash_player.exe).
2. Close all browsers.
3. Execute the uninstaller.
4. Reboot your computer.
5. Delete the following files and folders (if they still exist):

   ```
   %windir%\SysWOW64\FlashPlayerCPLApp.cpl
   %windir%\SysWOW64\FlashPlayerApp.exe
   %windir%\SysWOW64\FlashPlayerInstaller.exe
   %windir%\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash
   %appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player
   %appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player
   ```
6. Visit [Archived Flash Player versions](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) and download version 11.2 or lower.
7. Unzip the downloaded archive.
8. Run the installer.
9. When prompted, choose *Notify me to install updates* or *Never check for updates* to prevent Flash from updating automatically to 11.3 again.

Sources:

- [How do I revert to a previous version of Flash Player?](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1022066)
- [How do I do a clean install of Flash Player?](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4041846)

Comment: Flash 10.3 is recommended for a fully patched version. 11.2 has a couple more features, but also has some outstanding security holes. So, features or security? (take your pick!)