# Flash not playing in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I have a user who cannot play Flash files within IE. Flash files play ok within Chrome.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Uninstalled / Reinstalled Adobe Flash Player.
- Resetting IE settings, deleting temp files etc.
- Uninstalled IE 8, installed IE 9.

Not sure if it's related, but they can't play AVI files in Windows Media Player either. The DivX codecs are installed.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What happens when you have them go to this URL: http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ ?

Comment: If your using Flash 11.3, a downgrade might help. Possibly related: [Facebook videos don't play with IE9 & Flash Player](http://superuser.com/q/446524)

Comment: If the user goes to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ they see the Flash movie on this page. They are running version 11,3,300,265. Should I look at downgrading their Flash version still?

Comment: I followed http://superuser.com/q/446524, installing the latest version 10 of Flash, but the same issue remains.